# Remove character from string multiple times

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have the following string, where I would like to remove all instances of EUR

```
var str = "200.00 EUR, 33.33 EUR, 100.95 EUR, 300 EUR";
```

So the output is:

var str = "200.00, 33.33, 100.95, 300";

I tried

```
var res = str.replace("EUR", "");
```

But that only removes EUR one time.

Comment: `str.replace(/EUR/g, "");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this with a global replacement: by `/g` flag on [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Where,
**g** is global case-sensitive replacement

```js
var string  = '200.00 EUR, 33.33 EUR, 100.95 EUR, 300 EUR';
string = string.replace(/ EUR/g, '');
console.log(string);
```

> Global replace can only be done with a regular expression. In the
>   following example, the regular expression includes the global which
>   permits replace() to replace each occurrence of ' EUR' in the string
>   with ''

See Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/t7jz3h9k/11/

**As per comment:**

```js
var string  = '200.00 EUR, 33.33 PND, 100.95 DLR, 300 EUR';
string = string.replace(/ EUR| PND| DLR/g, '');
console.log(string);
```

Comment: Thanks! Will accept in 11 min ;-)

Comment: Can you explain why replace("", ) passing a string is not working?

Comment: @apples-oranges OK, glad it works for you. Best of Luck

Comment: What about the space between the number and comma?  This is the desired output `"200.00, 33.33, 100.95, 300"` @apples-oranges

Comment: @Ele Have you checked my edit? Please have a look and let me know is that ok? or may I need to change anything of my answer?

Comment: Good!, now it's an accpetable answer `:)` upvoted!

Comment: Thanks you Sir :) @Ele

Comment: You can also see the solution in a more elegant way with such recurring patterns:
    `var str = "200.00 EUR, 33.33 EUR, 100.95 EUR, 300 EUR";
    var result = str.split(',')
     .map(function(value, index) {
  return value.replace(/EUR/g,"");
     })
     .join(',');
console.log(result);`

Comment: Just a quik add on to this: what if I require to replace more than one character segment let's say: `200.00 EUR, 33.33 PND, 100.95 DLR, 300 EUR`

Comment: You can try quickly like this `string.replace(/ EUR/g, '').replace(/ PND/g,'').replace( /DLR/,'');`

Comment: @apples-oranges see my edit because the quick way I suggested on comment is not very efficient. Plz see my update

Comment: In my solution you can replace `value.replace(/EUR/g,"");` with `value.replace(/(EUR|PND|DLR)/g,"");`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)  to replace the string. Keep in mind string are immutable so original string will be unchanged.

```js
var str = "200.00 EUR, 33.33 EUR, 100.95 EUR, 300 EUR";
var str1 = str.replace( /\s*EUR/g, "");
console.log(str1);
```

> In string replace() it will search for the word 'EUR' and while it found
>   the required value it will replace with the given value. As it found the required value and replace it. it wont search any further. That's why you need regular
>   expression with /g flag. without /g flag it will work same

Comment: Can you explain why replace("", ) passing a string is not working?

Comment: It search for the word 'EUR' and while it found it replace with the given value. As it found the required value and replace it. it wont search any further. Thats why you need regular expression with /g flag. without /g flag it will work same

Comment: Please, put that comment in your answer

Comment: Additionally, all regexs in these answers are wrong because you're not replacing the spaces between the number and comma.

Comment: Good job, upvoted!

Comment: @Ele thanks for pointing out about space. :)

Comment: Take a look carefully `"200.00, 33.33, 100.95, 300"`

Comment: maybe try -> `/\s*EUR/g`  IOW: look for zero or more white-spaces followed by EUR.

Comment: @Keith you're right.

Comment: Now is perfect! `:)`

Comment: @Keith thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Easy, `str.replace(/EUR/g, '');`

Comment: Can you explain why replace("", ) passing a string is not working?